# Union of two variable sets

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

Given two lists of variables, what is the most compact and canonical way in ISO Prolog to determine the union of both?  That is, we want a definition for the  (meta-logical) predicates

```
varset_union(VarSet1, VarSet2, Union)
```

and for a list of lists

```
varset_union(VarSets, Union)
```

where `Union` is a list of unique variables of the given `VarSet`s.

Here is an [overview of the built-ins](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#status_quo) in ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995 including Cor.2:2012.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution using `term_variables/2`:

```
varset_union(VarSet1, VarSet2, Union):-
    term_variables([VarSet1|VarSet2], Union).

varset_union(VarSets, Union):-
    term_variables(VarSets, Union).
```

---

Solution using `setof/3`:

```
varset_union(VarSet1, Varset2, Union):-
    varset_union([VarSet1, VarSet2], Union).

varset_union([], []).
varset_union(VarSets, Union):-
    setof(Var, VarSet^(member(VarSet, VarSets), member(Var, VarSet)), Union).
```

Comment: Note that the definition with `setof/3` will produce a list of variables in implementation dependent order - which means essentially random order - whereas `term_variables/2` has a well defined order.

Comment: And in terms of efficiency the `setof/3` solution is much worse [at least in SWI-Prolog].

Comment: `setof/3` uses `term_variables/2` to determine the variables to be processed. And that is only the first step ...

Answer (score 2):

Based on Tudor's great answer, I have devised a definition of `varset_union/3` that is **more compact** by 2 characters:

```
varset_union(VarSet1, VarSet2, Union):-
        term_variables(VarSet1+VarSet2, Union).
```

;-)

Comment: In many implementations, this will be slower (like in SWI) and/or consume more space (like in SICStus, YAP).

Comment: I have strived for the criteria you asked for: Compact and canonical. Union and `+` are closely related, so it is at least very natural to use `+` here.